# Unity - how to put a target under a character's feet that follows ground model contours?

Tags: unity

In my current projects, one of the power-ups needs to place a target marker centered on the position of the player triggering it - the actual design for this is TBC, but will be a circle with a radius of 10 units.

The ground for the playing arena is a model, and not flat. Assuming that I use a texture to show this target area, how can I have this texture render following the contours of the ground?

Alternatively, any other approach to solving this would be appreciated.

Thank!